# Laravel vue donwloaded PDF file not loading

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to download pdf file from Laravel api with vue front end. Here is my vue code

```
methods: {
    downloadAttachment(file) {
      axios({
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/storage/app/public/files/owwhz8JkFjyTuE4SNMytTKjXbVWLLIkaPnaSUF9b.pdf',
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'blob', // important
      }).then((response) => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'file.pdf');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
      });
    }
  }
```

Now when i execute the method, it downloads a pdf file but says "Failed to load pdf document"
[image]

what's the error here ? Do I need to change anything in Laravel Api ?

Comment: Please change the Url: http://localhost:8000//files/owwhz8JkFjyTuE4SNMytTKjXbVWLLIkaPnaSUF9b.pdf  and please run php artisan storage: link command if you did not run it previously

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already created the symlink in Laravel, I think you are missing the type when creating your Blob instance.

So change your code from

```
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
```

to

```
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' }));
```

Also check your URL. If it's a public file, strip off the /app/public/ part, so that your URL becomes http://localhost:8000/storage/files/...